# Symfony key array in twig

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I want to show information from one entity.

The entity that has the information is related to another , so I use a query to obtain that information.

```
class Playlist
{
    private $id;

    private $name;

    private $items;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addItem(\Publicartel\AppBundle\Entity\PlaylistContent $content)
    {
        $content->setPlaylist($this);

        $this->items->add($content);

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeItem(\Publicartel\AppBundle\Entity\PlaylistContent $content)
    {
        $this->items->removeElement($content);
    }

    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }
}

class PlaylistContent
{
    private $content;

public function setContent(\Publicartel\AppBundle\Entity\Content $content = null)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

}
```

// The controller:

```
$playlists = $em->getRepository('PublicartelAppBundle:Playlist')->getAllPlaylist();

return $this->render('PublicartelAppBundle:Player:calendar.html.twig', array( 
'playlists' => $playlists,
));
```

// The query

```
public function getAllPlaylist()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $dql = 'SELECT p, cnt, plc FROM Publicartel\AppBundle\Entity\Playlist p
                LEFT JOIN p.items cnt
                LEFT JOIN cnt.content plc';

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($dql)
            ->setHydrationMode(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

        return $query->execute();
    }
```

The consultation seeks elements of the content entity, so it takes a left join on ' items' and 'content'.

// The twig template

I have sought access to the element of two ways:

```
{% for playlist in playlists.items.content %}
    <img src="/{{ playlist.path}}"> 
{% endfor %}
```

Key "items" for array with keys " 0, 1 " does not exist in PublicartelAppBundle : Player : calendar.html.twig at line 215

```
{% for playlist in playlists %}
    <img src="/{{ playlist.items.content.path }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Key "content" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist in PublicartelAppBundle:Player:calendar.html.twig at line 223

'Path' is an attribute for entity 'Content' that I want show.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to loop like this:

```
{% for playlistContent in playlists.items %}
    {% if playlistContent.content is not null %}
        <img src="/{{ playlistContent.content.path }}"> 
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**:

That found:

```
{% for playlist in playlists %}
    {% for playlistContent in playlist.items %}
        <img src="/{{ playlistContent.content.screenshot}}">
        <img src="/{{ playlistContent.content.path}}">
    {% endfor %}    
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

playlists.items is an array of objects not an object. Therefore you must loop through it.